# The phone conspiracy

Tags: discussion

So, this question
[Does not having a mobile phone disadvantage me in the job market?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/155155/does-not-having-a-mobile-phone-disadvantage-me-in-the-job-market)

is confusing quite a few users trying to help:

"Not having to pay for the phone's data plans has saved me thousands of dollars over the years;"

I assume the user is talking about uber-expensive mobile plans in the US. But this user does not want to disclose her/his country of origin. I think it's a bit excessive, unless I am missing something. Should the question stay as it is?

Comment: There's no basis for changing the claimed cost. And why bother anyway? What's the difference?

Comment: The lack of country information clearly confused many other users, and there is no good reason not to add it, there is no SWAT squad waiting at the door...

Answer (score 4):

> But this user does not want to disclose her/his country of origin. I think it's a bit excessive, unless I am missing something. Should the question stay as it is?

Well, the question is quite answerable and has already gathered good answers, including one that is yours...

Besides, including a country or wondering how much the phone plan is has few to nothing to do with the core question ("*Does not having a mobile phone disadvantage me in the job market?*").

Questioning OP why they don't want to spend on a mobile phone plan, or questioning if the plans in their country are that expensive is not helpful, nor relevant to the question asked.

IMO, I say the question is fine as it is.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not in the US, but we use (Australian) dollars.

My phone+data plan has been about $50 pcm for the last 10 years or so (so, $6,000). That's about middle here. Typically, cheapest phone+data is $30.

If you want less, you have to buy a phone and go prepaid, which could still tip over $1,000 "over the years".

IMO The OPs claim isn't too outrageous.

Answer (score 2):

The question is fine as it is.

You are always going to get XY comments and sometimes answers.

Maybe some of the comments are useful to the OP. Maybe some of the comments help understand what might be the mindset of the recruiter.

If there is one problem, it's that the question attempts to justify the point of view. That invites people to comment on the rationale. If they say: "I don't have access to a mobile phone" and leave it at that, there is likely to be less noise.

Answer (score 0):

Whole question looks wrong to me. I don't have a data plan for my phone, I rarely ring out. So it costs me peanuts. Isn't it the same in other places? Why would you get a data plan if you only need the phone to answer calls?

Comment: This https://www.moneysavingpro.com/cell-phone-plans/comparing-us-and-uk-bills/

Comment: So don't buy a plan, just buy a phone. I got a phone which gives me a phone number, no need for a plan after that unless I want to ring out. Yet I answer probably 5 - 10 calls a day which costs me nothing. The caller has to pay I assume.

Comment: My understanding is that in the US it is very common to spend that much, and the OP, instead of finding a cheaper alternative, is discarding having a phone altogether.

Comment: @Monoandale my understanding is that it's a troll wasting our time

Comment: you might be right